# How to publish web site to multiple web servers with TFS2013?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, publish

I have a solution with a web project. The project has a publish profile tfs.pubxml (MSDeploy as WMSVC) to deploy site to some WEB01 server. My question is what is the best practice to deploy site to multiple servers (5-10) with the same configuration.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install Release Management for TFS 2013. This will let you create a simple release pipeline and have your site deployed to multiple web servers in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Although @MrHinsh 's answer seems legit, but if you don't want to do that, you can create a separate build definition for each server with its own publishing profile, and trigger them all.